# is Newton step be a descent direction for convex function?

Tags: convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, gradient-descent

If $f(x)$ is convex function , is  Newton step be a descent direction?

In the optimization, the Newton step is  $-\nabla^2f(x)^{-1}\nabla f(x)$ and $d$ is a descent direction if  $ d.\nabla f(x) < 0 $

I know when $f$ is a convex function, we have always $\nabla^2f(x) >0$ but how I can show when $d=-\nabla^2f(x)^{-1}\nabla f(x)$ then $ d.\nabla f(x) < 0 $ ?

I read this statement :

Now, since $\nabla^2f(x)$ is positive definite, $\nabla^2f(x)^{-1}$ is also positive definite and therefore $$ \forall \nabla f(x)  \; \; \; \nabla^2f(x)^{-1}\nabla f(x) \cdot \nabla f(x)>0.$$

I can't understand it. Why for all $y$ the inequality hold?

since $\nabla^2f(x)$ is positive definite, $\nabla^2f(x)^{-1}$ is also positive definite and therefore $$ \forall y, \; \; \; \nabla^2f(x)^{-1}y\cdot y>0.$$  this is true for case of  $\nabla^2f(x)^{-1} >0$ 
How can show for case of $\nabla^2f(x)^{-1} =0$

Comment: If $A$ is a positive definite matrix then $(A y )^\top y = y^\top A y > 0$ for any $y$.

Comment: ok :-))))) . tes it is . thanks a lot @angryavian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

f must be strictly convex ,then  $\nabla^2f(x)$ is positive definite,  $ \nabla^2 f > 0$ .
 Now, since $\nabla^2f(x)$ is positive definite, $\nabla^2f(x)^{-1}$ is also positive definite and therefore $$ \forall \nabla f(x)  \; \; \; \nabla^2f(x)^{-1}\nabla f(x) \cdot \nabla f(x)>0.$$

When f be a convex and not strictly , maybe determinant equal zero and $  \nabla^ 2 f^ {-1}$ is not exist